# How to check if my string input followed the correct syntax in C++?

Tags: c++, string, design-patterns, indexing

I'm new to this site and this is my first time to ask here.

My problem is I want to check if my string follows a correct pattern or syntax. I'm doing it with C++ String (std::string). I have already done this using C-Style string, however, I want to do it this time in C++ String. Sample problem below:

Input: **2y'' + 3y' - 2y = 0**
or **y'' = 4y**

I want to check if the derivative input is in correct syntax like (a)y'' + (b)y' + (c)y = 0, a second order homogeneous equation. However, I still want to input a non-standard form equation like the second sample input that can be transposed and make it to standard form.

What I did before with it is remove all the white spaces, loop the entire string and check every index. Eg. if 'y' is found the next char should be `'\''` or an arithmetic symbol like `'-'` or `'+'` or `'='` then if it does not match, then, it must return false.

Or maybe I am just implementing this wrong. I'm new to programming and just taking a computer science course. Note: Sorry for my bad English and sorry if I did not written my code here. Its just way too long.

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) might be the answer. They're commonly used for checking whether a string first a format, or finding parts of a string that do.

[RegExr](https://regexr.com/) is a great tool to both learn and test your regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I look at it first and study it and maybe I can make it work on my program(project).

Comment: I think i'm getting the idea of regex. However, I am struggling to make a better implementation for this. Second Order Linear Equation with Constant Coefficient has many different equations. The first characters must be a coefficient or ```'y'``` then followed by a single quote ```'\''``` then followed by a sign. My goal is on how to make it work like if the input doesn't find it correct, it must return an invalid value(but this is not much of a difficult).

Sample input would be like(these are all just the same):
**y'' - 4y = 0**, 
**y'' = 4y**, 
**0 = y'' - 4y**